# How long has the Shahnameh been considered the national epic of Greater Iran?

Tags: persian-language, shahnameh, ferdowsi

According to the [Wikipedia article about the *Shahnameh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahnameh), this work by the Persian poet Ferdowsi "is the national epic of Greater Iran". The article adds that

> Iran, Azerbaijan, Afghanistan, Tajikistan and the greater region influenced by Persian culture such as Armenia, Dagestan, Georgia, Turkey, Turkmenistan and Uzbekistan celebrate this national epic.

The source for this claim is the BBC article [The Book of Kings: The book that defines Iranians](https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20180810-the-book-of-kings-the-book-that-defines-iranians), but this article does not tell us when the *Shahnameh* began to be considered "the national epic of Greater Iran".

There is no information about this in other sources I have consulted, such as the article [The Shahname of Firdowsi](https://www.angelfire.com/rnb/bashiri/Farr/iranhistdawn.html) by Iraj Bashiri and the [anonymous introduction](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Persian_Literature,_Comprising_The_Shah_Nameh,_The_Rubaiyat,_The_Divan,_and_The_Gulistan/Introduction_to_the_Shah_Nameh) to *Persian Literature, Comprising The Shah Nameh, The Rubaiyat, The Divan, and The Gulistan* on Wikisource.
This leaves my question unanswered: How long has the Shahnameh been considered the national epic of Greater Iran?